# Gauge percent similarity of line drawings in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm attempting to take two images in OpenCV, both drawn with a program like MS Paint or a simple drawing app, and gauge their percent similarity to each other. I have passing familiarity with some OpenCV image processing methods, but the approaches I've tried so far haven't been effective.

What I've thought of doing so far has been:

- Simplest approach - comparing the two images pixel by pixel. This is easy to code up but scale / rotation invariant. The solution needs to be able to recognize an imperfect version
- Hausdorff distance. This seems readymade for this problem, and I read a couple of other stack overflow posts about using it, but it takes in contours and I'm not sure how to extract contours from one image and match them to contours in another. One of the images might be empty, or they might be drastically different.
- Feature extraction / matching - The approach I've tried so far has been to use feature detectors (ORB, AKAZE) paired with a Flann-based matcher, and have gotten extremely poor results so far. I'm currently changing this to SIFT/SURF and brute-force, but it doesn't seem like this has worked very well.

What are other possible computer vision algorithms I can try? I attached two sample images that are representative of what I'm trying to compare (and I did grayscale the image before processing, so color is not a factor).

Thank you!

[image: Reference image 1 (will be tested against user drawing)]

[image: Reference image 2 (will be tested against user drawing)]

Comment: You don't need OpenCV - I can tell you they're pretty dissimilar by eye 

Comment: Lol @MarkSetchell you really made me laugh. But getting serious, Almond, if someone tells you to compare apples and pears... what would you tell them? you need to first think what are you going to compare, in the fruit example, you can compare sweetness or color. In this you have to decide what is the best way. 1st approach assumes that it is almost the same image, 2nd one... you can google find contours opencv, probably even the distance metric is already implemented, 3rd one no idea how you plan to get similarity through features, but this drawing are really bad for features.

Comment: As a side note, I think your question is too broad for this site. Too many possible solutions, something like how to find the contours to do the Hausdorff distance would have been more appropriate.

Comment: you dont need contours for hausdorff distance. Just threshold your images (drawn pixels to black) and use distance transform. That would've been my suggestion. If you want to make it invariant to translation and scaling, compute center of gravity and average distance of all drawn pixels and normalize them to image center and image size.

Comment: but try "modifief hausdorff distance" instead of the original one ;)

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I wish we could train computers to do that too :)

Comment: that makes sense, thank you for the suggestions! I should have been clearer on the question and probably narrowed it down - these were just reference images, the goal is to compare something the user drew to try and mimick these two. I really like the suggestion with distance transform (and computing average distance / center of gravity for invariance) and will probably implement that solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Micka - to clarify, once I get the distance transforms, would I pass those into modified hausdorff?

Comment: First of all, how do you define the similarity? Or, which similarity measurement do you want to choose? Is it suitable for your sketches? You choose the method, the the computer do the processing.

Comment: Hausdorff: you'll have to compute the distances from drawn pixels to drawn pixels in the other image. With distance transform you can compute the DT once for an image and then just read the distances for any pixel location, so it is just a simplification during hausdorff distance computation.

Comment: @Micka - that makes sense! I also implemented translation and scaling invariance using center of gravity, and it's working really well! :) However, I'm still a little bit confused on Hausdorff and DT, even though I did some research into it myself too. I applied DT to each cv::Mat, but the Hausdorff distance extractor (something like http://answers.opencv.org/question/60974/matching-shapes-with-hausdorff-and-shape-context-distance/) still only takes in contours. Are you suggesting that I just compute the DT and compare the values of each pixel in each image?

Comment: Clarification: the DT i've been looking at is between an image and the background. How would you call a DT between two images and pass the result to a Hausdorff Extractor?

Comment: Apologies for being slow but I think I am starting to understand it. Say you're comparing two images of size 500x500 - call them 1 and 2. Compute the inverse DT on image 2, so each pixel value represents nearest distance to a drawn point. On image 1, iterate through all drawn pixels. If pixel (137, 137) is drawn in image 1, I should look up the value of (137, 137) in image 2 and add that to the total score. Is that a good approach?

Comment: yes, this is the way to go, but afair in Hausdorff Distance you don't accumulate distances but just choose the biggest distance. In Modified Hausdorff Distance I'm not sure what they do choose. You could try chamfer distance, too (average distance). But be aware, that you might have to compute the scores (whichever you choose/try) in both directions, so for every active (drawn) pixel in image A you want to find the closest active pixel in image B but also the other way around, because otherwise, (nearly) empty images will appear very similar to everything.

Comment: I would love to implement it for you (wanted to do something similar myself), but unfortunately I won't have any spare time left this year.

Comment: No worries at all! Thank you - it's been an incredible amount of help so far. Just one last question - I have an implementation but I'm getting an incredibly weird bug - basically the hausdorff distance to the same image is non-zero. Even though the pixel at (for example) 137x137 is 0, the value of it is non-zero after the distance transform. Am I misunderstanding how a DT works?